# Lucene Boolean Query on Not ANalyzed Fields

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, ravendb

Using RavenDB to do a query on Lucene Index.

This query parses okay:
X:[[a]] AND Y:[[b]] AND Z:[[c]]

However this query gives me a parse exception:
X:[[a]] AND Y:[[b]] AND Z:[[c]] AND P:[[d]]

"Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.ParseException: Cannot parse '( AND )': Encountered \"  \"AND"

I tried this on complexed index and simple reproduce cases and same result it seems once you go past three ands it blows up. Im using [[]] and not analyzed because i want exact matches (also sometimes values contain whitespace etc..) and from RavenDB I have veyr little control over the indexing.

Im wondering how I can rewrite the query to avoid the parse exception?

Answer (score 2):

This is now fixed in the latest RavenDB builds. See [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/da6c61f7bbeea1b1) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This looks rather like a bug in Lucene's QueryParser, perhaps try reporting this in the user mailing list.

As a bypass, you could create a BooleanQuery manually and add the terms you want yourself. Since they are not analyzed, and the query doesn't look too complicated, you may be better off without the query-parser.